# SQL will not insert into table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, vbscript, asp-classic

I apologies in advance for this question – but I have no experience in classic ASP, although I have tried, I just cannot figure it out.

I have been given the task of tweaking an existing system (until a replacement is found), which has been written in ASP/VBScript.

The issue I am facing is that when I retrieve some data using SQL that I can’t get the script to update the results into the table. The number of results can change each time a query is run.

For example; The data in table calculates the time someone is absent, and each time someone is absent it records the duration in one field, in another field it records the date and in another field gives the record a `value = 1`.

This part works.

What I’m trying to do is collate the total duration absence per date and insert that data into the same table with a `value = 2`.

The code:

```vb
Set rssum = conn.execute("select sum(total) as total, visitdate from table_1 where repid=" &  session("repid") & " and type=1 group by visitdate  ")

If rssum.eof Then
  While Not rssum.eof
    rstotal=rssum("total")
    rstotal=rssum("visitdate")

    'some code to generate nextid
    Set abrec = conn.execute(insert into table_1 (abid,repid,type,visitdate,total) values(" & nextid & ", " & session("repid") & ",2,'" & visitdate & "'," & total & ") 
  Wend

  rssum.movenext

  rssum.close
  Set rssum = Nothing
End If
```

When I run the script, and say I’m calculating 2 days worth of data, it returns 2 `type=2` entries, but duplicates the date for the first date.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**movenext needs to be at the end of the loop, but inside the loop**.  Otherwise it will repeat indefinitely.  I'm surprised you didn't get an infinite loop.

```
    while not rssum.eof

      rstotal=rssum("total")
      rstotal=rssum("visitdate")

      'some code to generate nextid

      set abrec = conn.execute(insert into table_1 (abid,repid,type,visitdate,total) values(" & nextid & ", " & session("repid") & ",2,'" & visitdate & "'," & total & ") 


      rssum.movenext
      wend
```

Comment: Brillaint... Thank you for your response. Definately did the trick!

Comment: Jonathan, you're welcome, and if you like the answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues here.

1.

```
if rssum.eof then

  while not rssum.eof
```

Think about the logic of this, you're saying ***if*** a condition exists ***then*** do this only when the condition doesn't exist.  You probably don't need a conditional statement at all, but if you want one which only applies to a non empty recordset then the way to do it is

```
if not (rssum.eof and rssum.bof) then
```

2.

```
set abrec = conn.execute(...)
```

This is an insert command not a select.  You don't have any output to populate a recordset, so lose `set abrec =`

3. You need quotes around your insert query
4. As Ekkehard points out you need to assign the values of rssum("total") and rssum("visitdate") to separate variables, don't use rstotal twice
5. As Kyle JV points out in another answer `wend` needs to come after rssum.movenext, not before.

Putting it all together, try

```
set rssum = conn.execute("select sum(total) as total, visitdate from table_1 where repid=" &  session("repid") & " and type=1 group by visitdate  ")

if not (rssum.bof and rssum.eof) then

  while not rssum.eof

  total=rssum("total")
  visitdate=rssum("visitdate") 

  conn.execute("insert into table_1 (abid,repid,type,visitdate,total) values(" & nextid & ", " & session("repid") & ",2,'" & visitdate & "'," & total & ")" 

  rssum.movenext
  wend

  rssum.close
  set rssum = nothing

end if
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you comments, i wrote this from memory (which i shouldn't have) and as you aptly hightlighted, there are errors, what i was trying to get at was how to create the looping mechanism

Comment: Fair enough.  Personally I prefer to use `do while not...loop` or `do until...loop` to `while not...wend` on the grounds that its easier (for an English speaker at least) to understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
if rssum.eof then        ' if        EOF
   while not rssum.eof   ' while not EOF
```

can't possibly work and assigning to `rstotal` twice:

```
rstotal=rssum("total")
rstotal=rssum("visitdate")
```

makes no sense either.